# Rstudio Project uses project directory, Makefile uses R script directory -- how to reconcile?

Tags: r, makefile, rstudio

In my project folder, I have a `data` folder and a `R` folder for scripts.

```
project_folder
===============
Makefile
-- data
   -- data_file.csv
-- R
   -- my_script.R
```

Rstudio sets the working directory to be the project folder, so in my R script I would load data like so:

```
my_data <- read.csv("./data/data_file.csv")
save(my_data, file="./data/data_file.RData")
```

However, Makefile sets the working directory to be the R script's folder, so to load the same data I need (note the `../` vs `./` as above)

```
my_data <- read.csv("../data/data_file.csv")
save(my_data, file="../data/data_file.RData")
```

then run `make`:

```
data/data_file.RData: R/my_script.R
    cd R;R CMD BATCH my_script.R
```

Because of this discrepancy, I can only use either Make or RStudio project. How to use both?

Comment: You could always do a test for `any(grepl("RStudio", .libPaths()))` and if it's `TRUE` change the location of the data file(s).

Comment: @hrbrmstr In both terminal and Rstudio `any(grepl("RStudio", .libPaths()))` is `FALSE`. What is it supposed to accomplish? `.libPaths()` simply points to where I install my R package.

Comment: Try: `any(grepl("rstudio", search()))` (that old method used to work but this should be a good replacement)

Comment: @hrbrmstr that works. Let's see if there's a more elegant solution that doesn't involve moving data files around.

Comment: That solution involves string manipulation, not data file moving

Comment: I see. So I can set a constant HOME to be either `. ` or `.. ` depending on the boolean result